# how to find out which set of lists is the most similar to an original one?

Tags: computer-science, dynamic-programming, html-lists, list-comparison

I am trying to get numbers out of some ordered lists, for example a list could be
'A B C D E', and the other:
'C B E A D H G F I J K'

So I have some trusted data, which is a set of ordered lists each associated with a String, and I am trying to evaluate which automated way is the best to retrieve the same lists given a string so that the list would match (or be as similar as possible to) the list of the same string in my trusted data.

I don't have a strong background in statistics, I was hoping you can refer to methods that I can use and links or resources that would help me understand how to implement them.

Answer (score 1):

The solution would depend on your notion of similarity. One popular similarity measure is the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) (number of letter additions, deletions and modification required to obtain one string from another).